# Ant replace token from properties file

Tags: ant

i would like to replace tokens in source files with Ant:

```
some test ${foo} other text ...
```

Tokens are contained in a properties file eg.:

```
foo=1
```

Actually this is easy if tokens in source files were like '@@foo@@' or 'foo' but i'm not able to replace whole token : ${foo}

I've succeed years ago but this time i've failed ...

Thanks

Comment: In other words, do same job as maven-resources-plugin with filtering but with Ant

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1232532/183172

Comment: google "ant expandproperties" this is part of filterchains

Answer (score 4):

This is somewhat similar to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232532/simulating-the-maven2-filter-mechanism-using-ant).

Properties are loaded from the file `properties.txt`.
The weakness here is that all occurrences of `${` in your input text are converted to `{` *before* the token substitution - which may well break things if that string appears elsewhere in the text.  If that is a problem, it still aught to be possible to adapt this solution.

```
<copy file="input.txt" tofile="output.txt">
    <filterchain>
    <replaceregex pattern="\$\{" replace="{" />
    <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens">
            <param type="propertiesfile" value="properties.txt"/>
            <param type="tokenchar" name="begintoken" value="{"/>
            <param type="tokenchar" name="endtoken" value="}"/>
    </filterreader>
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```