# ANT replacing strings in specified files using file with properties

Tags: ant, properties, replace

I have a properties in file dev.properties and they look like this:

```
test.url=https://www.example.com/
[...]
```

and in project files there is a token [[test.url]] which I want to replace by https://www.example.com/. I just want to define all tokens in dev.properties and use them in build script, but without modifying build script and I want to replace those tokens in a specified files like *.php, *.html, etc.

Can someone give me a suggestions how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html

Comment: Yes, I used replace. See: http://codepad.org/VCuyWEyn

However, maybe it is not very optimized way. Constructive comments would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
<copy file="input.txt" tofile="output.txt">
   <filterchain>
   <replaceregex pattern="\$\{" replace="{" />
   <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens">
        <param type="propertiesfile" value="properties.txt"/>
        <param type="tokenchar" name="begintoken" value="{"/>
        <param type="tokenchar" name="endtoken" value="}"/>
    </filterreader>
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```

Founded here: [Ant replace token from properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680362/ant-replace-token-from-properties-file)

Answer (score 1):

In the following Ant script, replace the `src-root` property with the root directory containing the tokenized files:

```
<project name="ant-replace-tokens-with-copy-task" default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <!-- The <copy> task cannot "self-copy" files. So, for each -->
        <!-- matched file we'll have <copy> read the file, replace the -->
        <!-- tokens, and write the result to a temporary file. Then, we'll -->
        <!-- use the <move> task to replace the original files with the -->
        <!-- modified files. -->
        <property name="src-root" location="src"/>
        <property name="filtered-file.extension" value="*.filtered-file"/>

        <copy todir="${src-root}">
            <fileset dir="${src-root}">
                <include name="**/*.html"/>
                <include name="**/*.php"/>
            </fileset>
            <globmapper from="*" to="${filtered-file.extension}"/>
            <filterchain>
                <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens">
                    <param type="propertiesfile" value="dev.properties"/>
                </filterreader>
            </filterchain>
        </copy>

        <move todir="${src-root}">
            <fileset dir="${src-root}" includes="**"/>
            <globmapper from="${filtered-file.extension}" to="*"/>
        </move>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: <replacetokens> needs to specify every token separately. I was thinking about something else. I mean, one <target> task for one file with properties. So, I can easy add any properties without changing ant task. My properties in files are stored as: [[my.property]]. Here what I am doing: http://codepad.org/VCuyWEyn

Maybe there is better way.

P.S. I can not paste code here due to amount of character limitations in comments. Which is really very weird to limit to very low amount.

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us exactly what you're looking for. Give us the smallest possible example that shows what's in dev.properties. Give us the smallest possible example of what a *.php file with tokens looks like. Copy the Ant script from the Codepad site into your question. And then show what you would like the final *.php file to be after the replacements are done.

Comment: File dev.properties (or whater name of file) contains some of properties that must be replaced in source code files. Example of dev.properties:

    project.cdn.url=https://cdn.example.com/
    project.cdn.fonts=https://fonts.example.com/
    [...]

Now, source code (no matters if it is html, php or css; could be any file) can contains "temporary variable" like in example:

    <img src="[[project.cdn.url]]" width="32" height="32" alt="Logo"/>

So, the goal is to replace all "variables" in source code that matching to properties written in specified file (here dev.properties).

Comment: First, you should edit your question to make it clear that the example token is like [[project.cdn.url]] and not @test.url@. Are the delimiters "[[" and "]]" required? The ReplaceTokens filter reader used in my answer only works with single character delimiters. "@" is the default, but "[" and "]" would also work. If you're unable to change the delimiters, consider using a <propertyset> <mapper> that will map property keys. For example, a <regexpmapper> under a <propertyset> can transform a "project.cdn.url" into a "[[project.cdn.url]]".

Comment: 1. Question is already edited.
2. Delimiters "[[" and "]]" can be replaced by "@".
3. Let me check your code and test hw it works.
4. I have a some problems with pasting code here due to the limitation of characters problem. Moreover, I use 4 spaces to indent every line as StackOverflow suggest, but still wasn't look good. I do not know why.

Comment: You used "copy & move" solution. What about "replace replacefilterfile" which I used in [link]http://codepad.org/VCuyWEyn[/link]. Of course, everything depends on what is needed to be done. In my case I sometimes minify and concatenate script, CSS files, and sometimes not. That's why I used solution as mentioned above.

Comment: It doesn't look like <replace> supports nested <filterchain> elements. <copy> does, so the "org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens" <filterreader> can be used. "ReplaceTokens" is nice because it automatically surrounds each property with delimiters. A <replace replacefilterfile="..."> doesn't. To use <replace replacefilterfile="...">, you can first transform the property keys with something like a <regexpmapper> under a <copy>, write the results to a file, and then read that file with <replace replacefilterfile="...">. As a side note, are you aware of the <expandproperties> filterchain?

Comment: "To use <replace replacefilterfile="...">, you can first transform the property keys with something like a <regexpmapper> under a <copy>, write the results to a file, and then read that file with <replace replacefilterfile="...">."

I do as you described, but little bit in a different way: http://codepad.org/nlRaeL7F

I'm sorry, but I can not paste the code here because StackOverflow has a large limit number of characters in a comment. I do not know why.

Answer (score 1):

You specified that you do not want to edit your build script so this answer does not qualify but may still be useful to other readers.

If you were willing to edit your target file to use the format ${test.url} instead of [[test.url]] then [ExpandProperites](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#expandproperties) would be an excellent choice.