# How can PMD HTML Report's Error Description Link Show Local Folder

Tags: ant, pmd

I am using PMD source code analyzer ([PMD](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.41.0/index.html)) for my java web project through ant task. The computer is offline (not connected to the Internet). Part of ant task is as follows:

```
<target name="pmd">

  <taskdef name="pmd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask">
    <classpath>
      <fileset dir="E:/pmd-bin-6.41.0/lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>

  <pmd shortfilenames="true" cachelocation="pmd.cache" encoding="UTF-8">

    <ruleset>web/resources/category/java/bestpractices.xml</ruleset>

    <formatter type="html" tofile="report.html">
    </formatter>

    <fileset dir="src/java/">
      <include name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
  </pmd>
</target>
```

When I run `pmd` target, `report.html` file is generated ok. The html file basically lists <fileName, lineNumber, **description**> triplets.

e.g.

foo.java...43...`The initializer for variable "tempIDNo" is never used (overwritten on lin 67)`

The **description** in this html file has a link as `file:///E:ws/project/${pmd.website.baseurl}/pmd_rules_java_bestpractices.html#unusedassignment` which does not work. `E:ws/project/` is the folder where my project resides.

As a matter of fact, I have all the necessary html files (such as pmd_rules_java_bestpractices.html) unzipped in `E:/pmd-doc-6.41.0` folder.

Could you please help me how to set up **description** link in html file to show local folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have come up with:

1. (Using suggestion from ([How can I create a link to a local file on a locally-run web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page))) Before ant `pmd` target define property pmd.website.baseurl

```
    <propery name="pmd.website.baseurl" value="file:///E:/pmd-doc-6.41.0"/>
```

2. (Using usage/suggestion from (https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#expandproperties), [ANT replacing strings in specified files using file with properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987556/ant-replacing-strings-in-specified-files-using-file-with-properties) ) Change inside target as follows

```
...
<pmd ...>...
</pmd>
<copy file="report.html" tofile="report2.html">
  <filterchain>
    <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ExpandProperties"/>
  </filterchain>
</copy> ...
```

3. Run the ant target.