# Share filter file amoung modules

Tags: maven

I have the same question as this poster

[How to share a filter file among Maven2 modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528254/how-to-share-a-filter-file-among-maven2-modules)

share filter file among all sub projects and sub projects of sub projects

I implemented the solution provided by Rich Seller...this particular one and it works.
"Alternatively, you can specify a filter file as an attached artifact on some build"

But at the end of the build, i get an error message

### Installing /..../spring/hibernate/search/src/main/resources/shared-filter.properties to    /.../spring-hibernate-search-1.0-SNAPSHOT-filter.properties

[ERROR]BUILD ERROR
Error installing artifact: File /..../spring/hibernate/search/src/main/resources/shared-filter.properties does not exist

I am guessing Maven is trying to install the artifact proivded in the parent pom

```
<configuration>
    <artifacts>
        <artifact>
             <file>src/main/resources/shared-filter.properties</file>
             <type>properties</type>
             <classifier>filter</classifier>
        </artifact>
    </artifacts>
</configuration>
```

Is there a way to tell Maven not to install this artifact while building the childrens

PLEASE HELP, STUCK ON THIS FOR A WHILE

***********new addition***************

my parent pom has the following

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>src/main/resources/filters/mradha.filter.properties</file>
                                    <type>properties</type>
                                    <classifier>filter</classifier>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com.merc</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>MavenMasterProject</artifactId>
                                        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                        <classifier>filter</classifier>
                                        <type>properties</type>
                                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                        <destFileName>mradha.filter.properties</destFileName>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                                <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/filters
                                </outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
```

My sub project or modules have the following

```
<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>${project.build.directory}/filters/mradha.filter.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When i click on the sub project or module and do install, it tries to install the attached artifact and I get the build failure

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed exactly the same problem. We have even more nested structure of projects and I defined 'filters.path' property first

```
<properties>
    <filters.path>../../filters</filters.path>
</properties>
```

The structure of projects (filtering rules) matched following pattern:

```
<filters>
    <filter>${filters.path}/filter-${env}.properties</filter>
    <filter>${filters.path}/filter-shared.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

I have only 2 projects where custom filtering was required and i just changed the 'filters.path' property

```
    <properties>
        <env>dev</env>
        <filters.path>../filters</filters.path>

        <jbehave-revision>3.4.5</jbehave-revision>
        <xmlunit-revision>1.3</xmlunit-revision>
        <scale4j-revision>0.2</scale4j-revision>
    </properties>
```

Hope this can help!

Comment: simple and easy one to configure the filters in child module declaring the properties in parent module! - It worked! Thanks @Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Is the xml snippet posted above present in each children?  If so, that explains the problem.

If you carefully go through the steps suggested by @Rich Seller in the linked SO post, the parent project should `attach` the filter artifact using `build-helper-maven-plugin`. The children which require filtering should use `maven-dependency-plugin` to have this filter available during the `generate-sources` phase.  They should then use the filter using the `<filter>` and `<resource>` tags.

Comment: I have added the contents of my parent and sub project poms to the above post. Please take a look. As far as i know i am doing exactly the same as mentioned by Rich Seller

Comment: Hmm! in one place it is shared-filter.properties and in another mradha.filter.properties.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: that is a copy paste error. I copied the actual code in the previous post by Rich Seller. Then I added my own code. Are you actually using this implementation or based on the code you are guessing that it should work.