# Maven2 sharing dependencies across parent and children (without redeclaring dependencies in children)

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, dependency-management

With maven1 I was using the **extend** tag to tell my children project to use their parent configuration.

All dependencies declared in the parent were available in extending (children) projects.

Now with maven2 I'm using the inheritance/composition feature and I have to redeclare my dependencies (minus the version number) in every child project.
(see [how-to-share-common-properties-among-several-maven-projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231561/how-to-share-common-properties-among-several-maven-projects))

Is there a way to tell maven that I want to share some of my dependencies among all my children ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Now with maven2 I'm using the inheritance/composition feature and I have to redeclare my dependencies (minus the version number) in every child project

No, you don't. Dependencies declared in the parent pom are inherited.

> Is there a way to tell maven that I want to share some of my dependencies among all my children ?

Just declare the `<parent>` element in child POMs. For example, with this parent POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Demo - Parent</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <modules>
    <module>child</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

And this POM for the child module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <name>Demo - Child</name>
  <artifactId>child</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

The junit dependency gets inherited as expected:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'dependency'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Demo - Child
[INFO]    task-segment: [dependency:tree]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] my.group.id:child:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

I suspect that you are declaring dependencies in [the `<dependencyManagement>` section](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) (which has another purpose).