# How to declare global dependency for all submodules with maven and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, multi-module

I have multimodule structured maven project as follow:

- parent

  - server
  - shared
  - client

For me it is obvious that I would write unit test for all of those projects. So I thought that will be enought to add dependency to parent's pom.xml as follow:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and then in each submodule use it, f.e.:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
```

but I am getting errors in Eclipse like: `The import org.junit cannot be resolved`

When I do Maven-> Update project, or `mvn clean install`, there are no errors at all.

I refer to the parent module in a children one as follow:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>pl.daniel.erp</groupId>
    <artifactId>erp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Please help

Comment: Did you declare the parent in the child poms?

Comment: I've updated post-check it. thx

Comment: Hmmm. I would go through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211643/maven2-sharing-dependencies-across-parent-and-children-without-redeclaring-depe and if that's not an issue, try a full clean build from Eclipse. Likely a silly config issue or Eclipse acting up and needing a full clean.

Comment: Did you declare child modules dependencies in parent module pom?

Comment: You mean '<modules>' ?Yes.

Comment: `Maven-> Update` in Eclipse and the errors go away?  Then you've fixed the problem!

Comment: Tried already. Did not helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AJNeufeld:**

> "but you must still specify the dependencies in the child modules"

It is correct only if dependency is in <dependencyManagement>. Just try to set <dependency> in parent <dependencies> and do not set same dependency in child at all.

Parent POM:

```
<project>
 ...
 <dependencies>
   ...
   <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.12</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   ...
 <dependencies>
 ...
</project>
```

Child POM:

```
<project>
  ...
  <!-- no junit dependency defined at all -->
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: So what is the diference between `<dependencyManagement>` and `<dependencies>` tags? Why both exists?

Comment: <depenedncyManagement> is kind of "abstract" declaration (same idea as Abstract class :) Anywhere In parent projects tree it can declare common settings (i.e. version, scope etc.), but dependency will be added into classpath only when it is defined in <dependencies>. When it is in dependencyManagement, actual dependency needs to have only groupId/artifactId. So there are a lot of room for hierarchical settings... Same is correct for <plugins> and <pluginManagement> in <build>. And with plugins it is much more useful, since they may have large specific configurations.

Comment: So... "grand-parent" can have <pluginManagment> with common settings, then its children may have actual <plugin> with specific settings and all their "children" do not need to define plugin at all... Something like that. Actually in reality I have more than 100 such projects. And all dependency versions and plugins are defined in only one place. It is easy to manage with version upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure dependencies in the parent, but you must still specify the dependencies in the child modules.
This allows you to specify the version **once** in the parent POM, and have all child modules use that version.
Each child module must still list its dependencies, though.

Parent POM:

```
<project>
   ...
   <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
              <groupId>junit</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
              <version>4.12</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
         ...
       <dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   ...
</project>
```

Child POMs:

```
<project>
   ...
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>junit</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       </dependency>
      ...
   </dependencies>
   ...
</project>
```