# Change version of pom.xml of all maven projects based on single common config file

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I want to change the version of pom file in all the projects based on single common config file.I have the property defined in parent pom file. But  tag version cannot be replaced with ${common-project.version} which is defined in properties of parent pom file. Is there way to achieve it.

Please find the example below.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <!-- PROJECT VERSION -->
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

I want to change the 'version' tag in all the projects based on single config file to remove the duplication.

Comment: Either you use [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) to handle this or you need to use Maven 3.2.X+ where you can define properties for the version.

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise . Sadly project uses Maven 3.0+. Any other  alternative please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share common properties among several maven projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231561/how-to-share-common-properties-among-several-maven-projects)

Comment: If you use Maven 3.0+ you can use versions-maven-plugin. Apart from that if you do release via maven-release-plugin you don't need to change that manually otherwise you are doing something wrong. Is this a multi module project ?

Comment: the release plugin has an update versions goal as well: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/update-versions-mojo.html but compared to the versions plugin its quite limited.

Comment: Write a shell script.

Comment: ${global.version} solved my problem. Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582054/maven-project-version-inheritance-do-i-have-to-specify-the-parent-version and @Yanflea answer.