# Maven variable for reactor root

Tags: maven-2

In a multi-module maven project, is there a variable that points to the root project folder?

- `${project.basedir}` points to the current project's directory,
- `${project.parent.basedir}` points to the parent project's directory,

but is there a variable that always points to the root directory (the one from which the maven command was executed), no matter from which project inside the reactor?

---

I realized that the problem I wanted to solve is pretty much unsolvable. I wanted a variable that pointed to either project.basedir, project.parent.basedir, project.parent.parent.basedir etc, whichever is higher. But since a project's parent pom need not be it's parent in the file system, my whole approach won't help. So I am accepting Pascal's answer because it answers my question (even if my question does not solve my problem).

Comment: But anyway it is disturbing, that if we would have created it, there would be such variable :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the root directory of a multi module maven reactor project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084629/finding-the-root-directory-of-a-multi-module-maven-reactor-project)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> is there a variable that always points to the root directory (the one from which the maven command was executed)

`user.dir` (the working directory) should be that directory.

Answer (score 42):

In the latest maven, you can use `${maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory}`.

Comment: With Maven 3.6.3 I determined, with the plugin goal configured in the submodule pom.xml, this will reference the module dir from which maven is run.  If running in development from a submodule dir it will not "reference upwards" as one might hope.   It is sufficient for most purposes, however.

Comment: If a ".mvn" directory (which may be empty) exists in the root of the multimodule project, this works 100% (again, with 3.6.3)

Answer (score 24):

In Maven 3, `${session.executionRootDirectory}` is "a variable that always points to the ... directory ... from which the maven command was executed."

Note that this is distinct from a property that gives the top-level root directory of a multi-module project, regardless of where in the directory structure `mvn` is executed from. Such a property does not exist to my knowledge, but you can use the `${basedir}/..` hack to achieve it. See [this thread on maven-users](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201304.mbox/%3CCADN69ymQJsxB16e=grt63uCr_zX72RKPxKEGcfW4K5-0Rd8FqA@mail.gmail.com%3E) for more details.

See also: [Finding the root directory of a multi module maven reactor project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3084629/1207769)

Answer (score 7):

Use [directory-maven-plugin with directory-of goal](https://github.com/jdcasey/directory-maven-plugin#directory-of-goal).

Unlike other suggestions:

- This solution works for multi-module projects.
- It works whether you build the whole project or a sub-module
- It works whether you run maven from the root folder or a sub-module (unlike `${session.executionRootDirectory}`
- There's no need to set a relative path property in each and every sub-module!

The plugin lets you set a property of your choice to the absolute-path of any of the project's modules. In my case I set it to the root module...
In my project root pom:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.commonjava.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>directory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>directories</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>directory-of</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <configuration>
                <property>myproject.basedir</property>
                <project>
                    <groupId>com.my.domain</groupId>
                    <artifactId>my-root-artifact</artifactId>
                </project>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

From then on, `${myproject.basedir}` in any sub-module pom always has the path of the project root module. And of course, you can set the property to any module, not just the root...

Answer (score 5):

Such property can be created using: [directory-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jdcasey/directory-maven-plugin).
Using the plugin's `highest-basedir` goal you can assign the root path to any property you specify.

Answer (score 5):

For me, there was a need for root directory during **variable interpolation**, not for plugins section - for local directory relative to root with hand-crafted jars. I know this is a bad practice to have local directory with jars, but this was a requirement of project.

Why I was unable to use different solutions:

- `${session.executionRootDirectory}` and `${user.dir}` are tied with directory from which maven command was executed. I want to refer to the same directory independently of directory, from which maven was launched.
- `${project.basedir}` ,as mentioned above, points to current project directory, so child modules will search for jars in wrong location.
- I had about 100 projects, so defining relative paths or usage of accepted answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012402/maven2-property-that-indicates-the-parent-directory) question is quite complex in my case.
- [Directory plugin](https://github.com/jdcasey/directory-maven-plugin) can be used only for plugin configurations, not for variable interpolation

So, in my case with bad requirements I have used **environment variable** which refers project root and used it in pom.xml. Use it as last resort, when other solutions do not work. Here is example, how I use environment variable in my case:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-maven-repo</id>
        <!--NOTE: export PROJECT_ROOT=<location>-->
        <url>file:///${env.PROJECT_ROOT}/local-repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 2):

As far I think, there is no such variable. There are only workaround like in accepted answer of [Maven2 property that indicates the parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012402/maven2-property-that-indicates-the-parent-directory) .