# Usage of maven ${basedir} in multi-module setup

Tags: maven, maven-2

I am using a local repository as described in [Maven: add a dependency to a jar by relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path).

The repository-url is defined in the topmost `pom.xml` as

```
<url>file:${basedir}/../3rdParty/maven-repository</url>
```

Also, the topmost `pom.xml` defines 2 modules

```
<modules>
    <module>sub1</module>
    <module>sub2</module>
</modules>
```

The problem is, that if a module (say `sub1`) defines a dependency that should be downloaded from the repository, and maven is called from the topmost directory, the `${basedir}` is not set to this directory, but to `sub1`, resulting in a wrong repository-URL.

So, say the project with the topmost `pom.xml` resides in

```
/Development/myproject/pom.xml
```

And the repository is in

```
/Development/3rdParty/maven-repository
```

Then the repository URL should be set to

```
/Development/myproject/../3rdParty/maven-repository
```

but it turns out it is set to

```
/Development/myproject/sub1/../3rdParty/maven-repository
```

which of course does not exist.

Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: Why don't you use a repository manager to maintain your artifacts?

Comment: Based on the given information your build is not realiable and not reproducible. This is a no go for a build.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Although it is annoying in your case, this is well-known and intentional. A maven project should know about its execution directory only, no matter in what context it is executed.

I asked almost the same question: [Maven variable for reactor root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146638/maven-variable-for-reactor-root) earlier, and the only answer that made sense was [to use `${user.dir}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146638/maven-variable-for-reactor-root/4159892#4159892), although it's hacky and will not work if you build from a module directory.

(There is also this very verbose solution: [Maven2 property that indicates the parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012402/maven2-property-that-indicates-the-parent-directory/1019431#1019431))

Answer (score 6):

You can determine the root directory of a module with this nice plugin:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.commonjava.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>directory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>directories</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>directory-of</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <property>maven-parent.basedir</property>
                    <project>
                        <groupId>my.group</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
                    </project>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Use the directory like this: `${maven-parent.basedir}`

Answer (score 3):

How about having multiple repos?

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ibm-jars-bundle-lv0</id>
        <url>file://${basedir}/ibm-jars-bundle/repo</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>ibm-jars-bundle-lv1</id>
        <url>file://${basedir}/../ibm-jars-bundle/repo</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>ibm-jars-bundle-lv2</id>
        <url>file://${basedir}/../../ibm-jars-bundle/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: This works...but I believe it can create unnecessary "ibm-jars-bundle/repo" directories in child directories when looking up a local dependency since the first repository definition (ibm-jars-bundle-lv0) is tried first which looks in the root of the current child directory and creates the directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I have an erro because
<url>file://${basedir} ...
Is replaced as
<url>file:///app
Note the 3 /

Comment: @LuisRoberto it works with 3 slashes: `Downloading from ibm-jars-bundle-lv0: file:///home/il/build/test-jar-bundle/ibm-jars-bundle/repo/foo/test-jar-bundl2/0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-jar-bundl2-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom`