# build plugin in multi-module maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module maven project that I am attempting to build.
The project structure is, generally:

- Parent project (pom)

  - Sub Module 1

    - Sub Module 1A
    - Sub Module 1B
  - Sub Module 2
  - Sub Module 3

Inside of the parent project POM, I have the **net.revel.code.formatter** plugin defined in my build section to format the JAVA code inside of all of the sub-projects.

One of the attributes that I have to define in the plugin is the location of the configuration file. The file is located in a resource directory inside of `Sub Module 3`

I have the location attribute specified as `${project.parent.basedir}/submodule3/src/main/resources/eclipse/formatter.xml`

The problem that I am running into is that when `Sub Module 1A` (as an example) is building, it seems that the `${project.parent.basedir}` is resolving to the parent directory for `Sub Module 1A` (which is `Sub Module 1`) instead of the root of the project (where the property is actually defined).

Could someone help me sort out how to resolve this?

Comment: Would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084629/finding-the-root-directory-of-a-multi-module-maven-reactor-project) work for you?

Comment: Have you tried the examples from the docs https://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/examples.html#Multimodule_Configuration ?