# Maven multi-module project with license plugin

Tags: maven, pom.xml, multi-module, project-structure

I have a multi-module [project](https://github.com/johncarl81/transfuse) in which I'm trying to set up the license plugin to manage all the licenses.  Here's the project setup:

```
─── transfuse-project
    ├── examples
    │   ├── helloAndroid
    │   │   ├── pom.xml
    │   │   ├── ...
    │   ├── integrationTest
    │   │   ├── pom.xml
    │   │   ├── ...
    │   ├── pom.xml
    │   └── ...
    ├── transfuse
    │   ├── pom.xml
    │   ├── ...
    ├── transfuse-api
    │   ├── pom.xml
    │   ├── ...
    ├── NOTICE
    └── pom.xml
```

Each pom.xml inherits from the transfuse-project pom.xml.  In the project pom.xml I have set up the license plugin to apply the NOTICE to the relevant files:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mycila.maven-license-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-license-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <header>NOTICE</header>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/.*/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>target/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/AndroidManifest.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <properties>
                    <year>2013</year>
                    <name>John Ericksen</name>
                </properties>
                <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
                <strictCheck>true</strictCheck>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>check-headers</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This configuration works if I build directly off of the root (transfuse-project).  The problem arises when I build the integrationTest example or api directly.  Maven cannot find the NOTICE file I provided in the project root:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.mycila.maven-license-plugin:maven-license-plugin:1.9.0:check (check-headers) on project transfuse-api: Some files do not have the expected license header -> [Help 1]
```

And what's worse, it finds another dependency's NOTICE file.  If I run `mvn license:format` in a sub-module it replaces all of the module's headers with the dependency's NOTICE file.

I believe I can add a NOTICE file within each sub-module to fix this problem and configure each sub-module pom with its own license plugin, but I would like to avoid that duplication if possible.  Is there some configuration or setup that will work with my project setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use an **absolute path** by using

```
<header>${basedir}/NOTICE</header>
```

If this doesn't work, try to [set a property to and in the parent module's basedir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019431/1916258) and use it:

```
<header>${main.basedir}/NOTICE</header>
```

A third option is setting a property at runtime:

```
mvn clean install -Dmain.basedir=path/to/main/basedir
```

**Edit:**

Ok, a whole other option is to execute the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) before your license plugin. But you have to make sure the parent attaches the NOTICE (with [maven-assembly-plugin plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/))

```
<plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.6</version>
         <executions>
           <execution>
             <id>unpack-parent</id>
             <phase>verify</phase>
             <goals>
               <goal>unpack</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
               <artifactItems>
                 <artifactItem>
                   <groupId>parent</groupId>
                   <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
                   <version>parent</version>
                   <type>pom</type>
                   <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                   <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/license</outputDirectory>
                   <includes>NOTICE</includes>
                 </artifactItem>
               </artifactItems>
             </configuration>
           </execution>
         </executions>
       </plugin>
```

The `header` changes then in:

```
<header>${project.build.directory}/license/NOTICE</header>
```

**Edit2:**

I came across the find-maven-plugin. I think this could work:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.goldin</groupId>
    <artifactId>find-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>find-notice-file</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>find</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
                <propertyName>notice.file</propertyName>
                <file>NOTICE</file>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: ah, I tried that as well.  Building from the root works, but building any of the sub-modules fails.

Comment: Spoke too soon.  This: ${project.parent.parent.basedir} does not seem to reference the grand-parent when built from the root.  Ideas?

Comment: would I add the dependency plugin to the root or each sub-module?

Comment: In the root, but the execution should be in the child poms

Comment: Ugh, ran into a bug in Maven with this solution: "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:unpack (unpack-parent) on project transfuse-project: Unknown archiver type: No such archiver: 'xml'."

Comment: I wonder, could I host the header online and reference it via url?  Seems like a huge workaround, bit may solve my relative path issues.

Comment: I found a plugin which searches a file in a parent path: http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Find-maven-plugin. I've added it to the answer

Comment: Edit2 works.  I like the fact that it is only defined in the parent pom.  Thanks again for your diligence, check mark well earned.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a much easier way to do this. Just set the `aggregate` tag to `true` in the configuration. Here's the full `maven-license-plugin` definition:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mycila.maven-license-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-license-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.b1</version>
    <configuration>
        <header>etc/header.txt</header>
        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You then just need to have a file called `header.txt` in `etc/header.txt` in the parent root directory.

Comment: This works when building the parent, but not when you build an individual module by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try your example with this two configuration properties set:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mycila</groupId>
  <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
  <configuration>
    <header>/NOTICE</header>
    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```