# Maven compile cannot resolve project.parent.basedir

Tags: maven, directory, parent

I  am using maven to compile `apache-hive-2.1.1-src` for debug reason ,I use `-X` paremeter to print out the debug information.
but finally , the compilation failed:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3:single (assemble) on project hive-packaging: Failed to create assembly: Error adding file to archive: /data/base/3rd/apache-hive-2.1.1-src/packaging/${project.parent.basedir}/common/src/main/resources/hive-log4j2.properties isn't a file. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3:single (assemble) on project hive-packaging: Failed to create assembly: Error adding file to archive: /data/base/3rd/apache-hive-2.1.1-src/packaging/${project.parent.basedir}/common/src/main/resources/hive-log4j2.properties isn't a file.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to create assembly: Error adding file to archive: /data/base/3rd/apache-hive-2.1.1-src/packaging/${project.parent.basedir}/common/src/main/resources/hive-log4j2.properties isn't a file.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:511)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.ArchiveCreationException: Error adding file to archive: /data/base/3rd/apache-hive-2.1.1-src/packaging/${project.parent.basedir}/common/src/main/resources/hive-log4j2.properties isn't a file.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.phase.FileItemAssemblyPhase.execute(FileItemAssemblyPhase.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:182)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:452)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: /data/base/3rd/apache-hive-2.1.1-src/packaging/${project.parent.basedir}/common/src/main/resources/hive-log4j2.properties isn't a file.
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.addFile(AbstractArchiver.java:375)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.archiver.AssemblyProxyArchiver.addFile(AssemblyProxyArchiver.java:463)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.phase.FileItemAssemblyPhase.execute(FileItemAssemblyPhase.java:113)
        ... 24 more
```

I have checked the pom file bin.xml whose name is definition where this error happened,it is :

```
<files>
    <file>
      <source>${project.parent.basedir}/common/src/main/resources/hive-log4j2.properties</source>
      <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
      <destName>hive-log4j2.properties.template</destName>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>${project.parent.basedir}/ql/src/main/resources/hive-exec-log4j2.properties</source>
      <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
      <destName>hive-exec-log4j2.properties.template</destName>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>${project.parent.basedir}/beeline/src/main/resources/beeline-log4j2.properties</source>
      <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
      <destName>beeline-log4j2.properties.template</destName>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>${project.parent.basedir}/llap-server/src/main/resources/llap-daemon-log4j2.properties</source>
      <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
      <destName>llap-daemon-log4j2.properties.template</destName>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>${project.parent.basedir}/llap-server/src/main/resources/llap-cli-log4j2.properties</source>
      <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
      <destName>llap-cli-log4j2.properties.template</destName>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>${project.parent.basedir}/common/src/main/resources/parquet-logging.properties</source>
      <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
      <destName>parquet-logging.properties</destName>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>${project.parent.basedir}/hcatalog/README.txt</source>
      <outputDirectory>hcatalog/share/doc/hcatalog</outputDirectory>
    </file>
  </files>
```

it seems that the parameter `${project.parent.basedir}` is not resolved to my hive home directory `/data/base/3rd/apache-hive-2.1.1-src`,instead it is resolved to `/data/base/3rd/apache-hive-2.1.1-src/packaging/${project.parent.basedir}`,very strange.Actually , the file 
 `/data/base/3rd/apache-hive-2.1.1-src/common/src/main/resources/hive-log4j2.properties` exits.
Anyone could give me some suggestions? My maven version is 3.3.9.Does it have anything to do with maven assembly?

The directory structure is :

```
hive-2.1.1/
    orc/
    ql/
    other modules/
    packaging/
       src/
          main/
              assembly/
                   bin.xml/ #the pom which throws the error.
                   src.xml/
    pom.xml
```

you can also check the directory from github :https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/packaging/src/main/assembly

Comment: There is no variable `${project.parent.basedir}` in maven. where have you set it?

Comment: Are you sure? but this is just the source code of hive.I just cannot find a place which define this variable. I find this page :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012402/maven2-property-that-indicates-the-parent-directory

Comment: Show your folder/directories hierarchical structure. because your path variable `${project.parent.basedir}` is wrong.

Comment: Hello,I have just updated my post with the folder structure.