# {project.parent.basedir} taking of path sub module rather than Parent module path

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have following structure in project

```
| prj
  | a1_module
     |src
     |pom
  | a2_module
     |src
     |pom     
  | lib 
     xyz.jar
  |pom(parent)
```

Now i register xyz.jar in sub module(a1_module) pom like this:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.asd.prj</groupId>
    <artifactId>pubsub</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.parent.basedir}/lib/pubsub_2.11-1.0.0-SNAPSHOTjar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I expect `${project.parent.basedir}/lib/pubsub_2.11-1.0.0-SNAPSHOTjar` should give me `prj/lib/pubsub_2.11-1.0.0-SNAPSHOTjar` but it gives me path like this `prj/a1_module/lib/pubsub_2.11-1.0.0-SNAPSHOTjar`.

Beacuse of this situtaion i get error as there is no jar kept in sub-module but its kept outside in "lib" directory of main project.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012402/maven2-property-that-indicates-the-parent-directory) says that `project.parent.basedir` should give path of parent of that module path but in my case its giving me path of submodule rather parent module path.

Any suggestion that what i am doing wrong or what is other way to register my local jar in submodules.

Comment: Remove a system scope dependency and don't use such lib directory constructs...They really bad things in Maven. Better start using a repository manager and deploy this jar into the repository manager...and afterwards use the jar as usual dependency...(I assume the pubsub-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar has been created by another Maven build?)

Comment: You are right @khmarbaise. I am going to follow repository manager way.
This is not the good way to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<systemPath>${basedir}/../lib/pubsub_2.11-1.0.0-SNAPSHOTjar</systemPath>
```

Comment: Tried this but still same issue.