# How to make sure Maven gets jar from parent lib folder and ignore for the submodules?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have a project structure like below:

```
- app
  - app-repo
  - app-service
  - app-controller
  - lib (custom jar placed here)
  - pom.xml (parent pom)
```

My parent pom include the submodules and a repository location to get jar from **lib** folder

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>in-project</id>
            <name>In Project Repo</name>
            <url>file://${main.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <modules>
        <module>app-repo</module>
        <module>app-service</module>
        <module>app-controller</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${project.basedir}</main.basedir>
        <jar.version>1.7</jar.version>
        <release.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</release.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>  <!-- jar file located in lib folder -->
            <groupId>com.custom</groupId>
            <artifactId>custom-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jar.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My maven build order:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] app                                                [pom]
[INFO] app-repo                                           [jar]
[INFO] app-service                                        [jar]
[INFO] app-controller                                     [jar]
```

and it failed with error when building **app-repo**:

```
Failure to find com.custom:custom-core:jar:1.7 in
file://C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\My_APP\app-repo/lib was cached in the local repository
```

What I found is maven inherits the **`<repositories>`** from parent pom during the submodules build, so **`<url>file://${main.basedir}/lib</url>`** is causing maven to look for app-repo/lib and hit the error.

So I would like to know what is the best practice to handle this scenario?

1. How to make sure maven will always get the jar from the **lib** folder and ignore for the submodules ?
2. What is the correct/best configuration for the parent pom.xml ?

I tried to add `<url>file://${project.parent.basedir}/lib</url>` into the child pom.xml in app-repo like below:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>in-project</id>
            <name>In Project Repo</name>
            <url>file://${project.parent.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

or

```
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
    </properties>
```

but both also seem like not able to refer to parent folder and hit below error

```
Failure to find com.custom:custom-core:jar:1.7 in
file://${project.parent.basedir}/lib was cached in the local repository
```

Comment: Do your child repos have their own pom.xml's? Perhaps in them you can specify <url>file:///${project.parent.basedir}/lib</url>.

Comment: Also, to clarify - do you mean "app-repo/lib" (not app-repository/lib)?

Comment: Yes, each child module have their own pom.xml. Let me try on this.

Comment: Start to use a repository manager and put the needed jar's in there instead in a lib directory... in relationship with Maven it violates the foundation of Maven

Answer (score 0):

After getting hints from J Woodchuck, I'm able to find a answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012402/maven2-property-that-indicates-the-parent-directory)

Since 3.0.4, `${parent.basedir}` is not longer available, so pom.xml in child need to be like this to make it able to refer to parent project directory:

```
<main.basedir>${project.basedir}${file.separator}..</main.basedir>
```